# How can I ensure what I'm about to str_ireplace isn't a part of a url?

Tags: php, regex

I've got the following code;

```
$array = ["example","exam ple"];
$message = str_ireplace($array, 'ExamPle', $message);
```

I'm trying to replace mentions of my website's name with the cute stylised version of it on pre-save, before it's inserted into the database.

What I have works, but if the mention of my website name is part of a URL (because the domain name is the website name) then it replaces that too, breaking the link.

How can I modify what I have to not replace URLs?

I thought of a way by exploding a user's post into an array and doing some kind of filter_var($string, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL); but it seemed flaky and hugely wasteful.

Is Regex the answer? using a preg_match_all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the url is `www.example.com` or just `http://example.com`.

Now, depending on your needs, you could choose one of these patterns:

*example* not preceded by `http://`, `https://` or `www.`: `(?<!http://|https://|www\.)example`
*example* not followed by `.com`: `example(?!\.com)`

Replace these with your stylized version, like that (for instance using the second pattern):

```
preg_replace('#example(?!\.com)#i', 'ExamPle', $message)
```

Enclose the pattern in `#`...`#i` for example to get case insensitivity.

The second pattern will exclude standalone mentions of *example.com* which should give better results. Suppose you have some user-posted content, where the user says: *...what I like about example.com is bla bla bla...*. In this case, the second pattern won't replace the *example* word, but the first one will nonetheless. I think it should remain lower case in this situation.

Now there's the case of strings like `http://something/example/something`, this can be solved in two ways.

**First solution:**

```
(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|example(?!\.com)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nV5uB9/2)

This works by matching URLs, consuming the full URL, and then failing the match while setting the next start offset at the end of the URL.

Code:

```
preg_replace('#(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|example(?!\.com)#i', 'ExamPle', $message)
```

**Second solution**, if you're not comfortable with backtracking verbs:

```
(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+|(example(?!\.com))
```

[See here](http://regex101.com/r/nV5uB9/1) to get an idea of how this pattern matches. Basically, any URL will match the left side of the alternative, and the string you want to replace will match the right side, and will be captured.

I don't have PHP installed and it's been a few years since I last used it, but something like this should work:

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '#(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)\S+|(example(?!\.com))#i',
    function ($matches) {
        if ($matches[1])
            return "ExamPle";
        return $matches[0]; // Do not substitute
    },
    $message)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I'm not trying to replace anything that's part of a URL. I'm trying to replace occurrences that aren't forming part of a URL, so that I don't break URLs. For instance, if someone says Example rocks, it'd be replaced. If they say http://example.com rocks, it wouldn't be replaced.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I'll give this a go. Your edits have made it clear your solution is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Actually, the syntax `(?<!...)` and `(?!...)` are negative lookarounds, they will pass if the string does *not* match what's inside them.

Comment: Insightful. Thank you.

Comment: Perfect. I've dabbled with regex, but "negative lookarounds" (basically flipping the logic) was alien to me. This works perfectly. Replacing every occurrence that isn't part of a url.

Comment: HTH. After a second thought, I'd rather go with the second pattern (`example(?!\.com)`) becuse it's simpler and should better filter out the results.

Comment: The site is 100% https. and it's .co.uk. I'm not sure if this still applies, as I'm not equipped to understand how this improves on your first answer. :\ Thanks. The example would be http s://example.co.uk (space to avoid SO filtering)

Comment: Then I'd go with `example(?!\.co\.uk)` - I've added an example I was thinking about to explain why.

Comment: Hi, I've discovered an issue with this, I wondered if you could help with, as I've tried all sorts. This works perfectly, except for when a posted link such as "http://example.com" (which if posted alone, is correctly excluded) if it has a URI also containing a mention of the brand name, such as "http://example.com/page/example/test" the link is broken by the second mention of it not being excluded in the negative look around. Thanks.

Comment: Wow, thanks for returning to help. You're a gent. :)

Comment: That works perfectly, I used the first one with the backtracking verbs, it looks odd, but is clearly perfectly valid regex so I'm off to read up on those. :)

Comment: HTH. Good luck, that's some more advanced stuff ;) but `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` is a common combo (an equivalent notation is `(*SKIP)(?!)`)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach, if you know exactly the text you're trying to "not replace into," is to use a dummy value. Replace your text that you want to keep safe with the dummy value, do your real search/replace, then replace you dummy value with your safe text. Like this:

```
$message = "This is http://www.example.com/index.html example text exam ple";
$array = ["example","exam ple"];
$url = "http://www.example.com";
$dummy = "**23ew0fjw0effw09ef0w9e8f0e9w**";

$message = str_ireplace([$url], $dummy, $message);
$message = str_ireplace($array, 'ExamPle', $message);
$message = str_ireplace($dummy, $url, $message);
```

The dummy text just has to be something that will, with very high probability, never ever appear in your text. It is also possible to search on it with `preg_replace`, if there are several possible forms of it. If you can replace all forms of your URL with one canonical form, then this simple technique still works. If you need to replace exactly the form of the URL that appears in the original text, a slightly more involved technique is needed, where each precise form is recorded.

This replace-with-dummy-then-replace-the-dummy do-so-do always seems a little clunky, but it works surprisingly well. I console myself with the fact that it's not so different from the fancily-named [Schwartzian Transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).